# How to run webpack compilation as part of CircleCI configuration

Tags: webpack, circleci

I would like to save my uncompiled files to Github and have CircleCI run `webpack` later on to compile it. I can't seem to get this to work...

```
machine:
  node:
    version: 5.10.1

dependencies:
  override:
    - npm install
    - npm install webpack -g
    - webpack

test:
  override:
    - npm test

deployment:
  staging:
    branch: master
    heroku:
      appname: heroku-app-123
```

Webpack does appear to have run, because I get the following output in CircleCI:

Hash: db00c1

```
e4b7e0aa25c885
Version: webpack 1.12.14
Time: 10581ms
              Asset     Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
 /images/iphone.png  79.9 kB          [emitted]  
/images/macbook.png   117 kB          [emitted]  
   /images/temp.png  16.1 kB          [emitted]  
          bundle.js  2.38 MB       0  [emitted]  main
          style.css  19.9 kB       0  [emitted]  main
   [0] multi main 52 bytes {0} [built]
...
```

But unfortunately, when it's deployed nothing is rendered, which tells me that webpack did not actually run. If I run the command `webpack` locally and push to Github, everything works fine, but I don't want to have to rely on me remembering to compile my app before I push.

Is my webpack compilation step simply in the wrong place? How do I solve this?

My `webpack.config.js` file looks like this:

```
var path = require('path')
var webpack = require('webpack')
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin')
var autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer')

module.exports = {
  devtool: 'eval',
  entry: [
    'webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:3000',
    'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',
    './app/index'
  ],
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'static'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    publicPath: ''
  },
  plugins: [
    new ExtractTextPlugin('style.css', {
      allChunks: true
    }),
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()
  ],
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loaders: ['babel'],
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        include: path.join(__dirname, 'app')
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style', 'css?modules&importLoaders=1&localIdentName=[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]!postcss!sass')
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg)$/,
        loader: 'file?name=/images/[name].[ext]'
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: [ '', '.js', '.scss' ],
    modulesDirectories: [ 'app', 'node_modules' ]
  },
  postcss: [ autoprefixer({ browsers: ['last 2 versions'] }) ]
}
```

Comment: What does your webpack.config.js look like?

Comment: @SeanLarkin Updated with config file.

Comment: Does Herkoku know to use your webpack build commands? Also, if you want to use Heroku to build your app, you should also be aware of where it will be built to and if that place is the proper location for whatever webserver you are using.

Comment: I'm not sure if it knows to build it. I'm telling it to build in the `dependencies` step, and it logs something so I think it's building. That said, the bundle never seems to change. It could be a simple configuration issue, but I haven't been able to track it down yet.

Comment: Any news on this issue? I'm thinking about using CircleCI for a project but if webpack isn't working then it is a no go.

Comment: @JohnP Ahh, yes, I solved it. Will update with the answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is to run your webpack build during deployment, like so:

```
...

deployment:
  aws:
    branch: master
    commands:
      - chmod +x deploy.sh
      - webpack --config webpack.prod.config.js
      - ./deploy.sh
```